# jQuery add class on scroll when hitting element

Tags: javascript, jquery

We use some jQuery to make our navigation sticky from some point on the page and to add an active class to sections on the page. 
Currently the class is added from a given height to top (645). 
But I want to add the class when the user scrolls over the given element, so that we don't need to add a given height. This because the height is variable for every page.

How can I fix this by adding this jQuery code?

Code:

```
<script>
$j(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $j('.menu-header-product'),
      scroll = $j(window).scrollTop();

  var elementOffset=jQuery("#productnav").offset();    
  if (scroll >= elementOffset.top - 57) sticky.addClass('sticky');
  else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
});
$j(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $j('.content'),
      scroll = $j(window).scrollTop();

  var elementOffset=jQuery("#productnav").offset();    
  if (scroll >= elementOffset.top - 57) sticky.addClass('sticky');
  else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
});
    $j(document).ready(function () {
        $j(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

        $j('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $j(document).off("scroll");

            $j('a').each(function () {
                $j(this).removeClass('active');
            })
            $j(this).addClass('active');

            var target = this.hash;
            $jtarget = $j(target);
            $j('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $jtarget.offset().top - 120 /**just subtract the height of the fixed html part */
             }, 500, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $j(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        });
    });

function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPosition = $j(document).scrollTop();
        $j('nav a').each(function () {
            var currentLink = $j(this);
            var refElement = $j(currentLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top - 125 <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top - 125 + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
                $j('nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
                currentLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currentLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the top pixel position of the desired element, using JQuery offset (http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

Change this line:

```
if (scroll >= 645) sticky.addClass('sticky');
```

to this:

```
var elementOffset=jQuery("#YOUR_ELEMENT_ID").offset();    
if (scroll >= elementOffset.top) sticky.addClass('sticky');
```

EDIT:

If your main header height is fixed, add this after you defined elementOffset

```
elementOffset.top=elementOffset.top-57;
```

Otherwise, retrieve the height of your header and substract that from the elementOffset.top in the following way:

```
headerHeight=jQuery("#HEADER_ID").height();
```

Comment: Great, that works!! :) But we already do have a header with height of 57px. So how can I fix this with top?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please rephrase your queston. If you would post some of your HTML code would also help.

Comment: Well on the page we do have a main header with the navigation menu for the entire website. This header is fixed. So when scrolling and scrolling over the element this one becomes also fixed below the main header. This main header does have a height of 57px. So with this addition you made, the elements becomes sticky when the entire main header is scrolled over the element. But I want it becomes sticky when the bottom of the main header hits the element.

Comment: Adam do you also know the solution for this? Currently the active is added to the a class inside the li. But how can I add the active class to the li?

Comment: I don't understand. If you mean "sticky" by "active", please show me the exact code(with the id you use) where you add it, and I will fix that too